# JQuery dataTable table.column not defined

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using currently DataTable, but I have this following error:

> table.columns is not defined

```
$selector.html(data);
var table = $selector.find('table').DataTable({
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
  initComplete: function() {
    table.columns().every( function () {
       var that = this;
       $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
         if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
           that
             .search( this.value )
             .draw();
         }
       });
    });
  }
});
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `table` is not yet defined when `initComplete` callback is called.

Change

```
initComplete: function() {
    table.columns().every( function () {
```

to

```
initComplete: function(settings){
   var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
   api.columns().every( function () {
```

Comment: it works thank you, but it didn't correct my problem. 
I mean, I put this because something went wrong when I put this code if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
           that
             .search( this.value )
             .draw();
         }
When i put more than some characters, its display nothing.
I thought If i put InitComplete, it will correct my problem but no.
Did you see some mistake in my code? @Gyrocode.com